# How to compile folder that contains bin, lib and share

Tags: compiling

I downloaded FileZilla from the website, and the file type is tar.bz2. I extracted it which is a folder contains bin, lib and share sub folders. Since there is no instruction of how to compile them and I am not so familiar with compiling, so I ask for help.

PS: I know I could use sudo apt install filezilla, but I would rather get to know how to compile so I can learn something.

Thanks

Comment: Did you actually download the *source* distribution - or one of the (default) binary distributions? What is the full name of the tar.bz file?

Comment: here is the link of the download, I only see this  https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?show_all=1

Comment: Hi, I just saw that there is an source code, I think that's what I need, but still, I am not sure how to compile it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiling instructions are documented on the [FileZilla Wiki](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Client_Compile),

> FileZilla 3 has the following dependencies:
>
> - libfilezilla
> - wxWidgets
> - GnuTLS
> - libidn (under Unix-like systems)
> - gettext (Compiletime only)
> - libdbus (under Unix-like systems)

Then to actually compile it,

> If all dependencies are installed, compiling FileZilla is as simple as calling
>
> ```sh
> ./configure
> make
> make install
> ```

This is pretty much the standard way of compiling and installing most free/libre and open source software on GNU/Linux.

Comment: Thanks, I am working on it, one question, since I compile the packages inside the main folder (within ~/Downloads), can I delete the folder once I successfully compiled it?

Comment: Yes, however then you will be unable to uninstall via `make uninstall`, (if supported by the Makefile). Traditionally, one would keep these sources in `/usr/src/` for later modification.